# Adding a custom command class to setup in setup.py no longer copies data files

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

I created a python package with the setup method from setuptools and it worked flawlessy.

I had this and it worked perfectly:

```
setup(
      name='whatever',
      version='1.0.0',
      packages=find_packages(),
      license='MIT',
      author='Sheldan',
      install_requires=['psutil', 
                        'itsdangerous', 
                        'flask', 
                        'python-crontab', 
                        'enum34', 
                        'requests', 
                        'kitchen',
                        'python-dateutil',
                        'flask-login'],
      include_package_data=True,
      data_files=get_data_from_folder('logs') + get_data_from_folder('resources')
)
```

Then I needed to execute some post installation steps. After some research, it seems I had to override the command which is executed. 
So I added `cmdclass={'install': install}` to the setup from above and added a class called install which looks like this:

```
class install(_install):
def run(self):
    _install.run(self)
    self.execute(_post_install, (self,),
                 msg="Running post install task")
```

`_post_install` is just a method, which executes the post installation steps.

But for some reason, after I added the command, the files which should be copied via data_files are now longer copied and I saw that the target path is no longer `'yt_crawler-1.0.0-py.2.7-egg'`, but simply `'yt_crawler'`

After some research it seems like the `'bdist_egg'` command is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by calling self.do_egg_install() instead of _install.run(self).